# Odd sum in array

Tags: data-structures

You are given an array A containing N integers. You have to answer Q queries.

Queries are of form:

L R

Here you have to fInd sum of all numbers
, for those which has odd frequency in subarray L to R
First line of input contains a single integer N, next line contains N space separated integers, elements of array A. Next line of input contains a single integer Q. Q lines follow each containing two space separated integer L and R.
Sample Input

5
1 2 2 2 1
3
1 3
1 4
1 5

Sample Output

1
7
6

Explanation

For query 1: 1 has frequency 1 and 2 has frequency 2 so, answer is 1

For query 2: 1 has frequency 2 and 2 has frequency 3 So, answer is 7
-----------------------------Solution---------------------------------------

{{

public class samsungTest 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    int q = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        int l = sc.nextInt();
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        findOddSum(arr, l, r);
    }
}

private static long findOddSum(int[] arr, int l, int r) 
{
    long sum = 0;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = l-1; i < r; i++ ) {
        if( map.get(arr[i]) == null ) {
            map.put(arr[i], 1);
        } else {
            int freq = map.get(arr[i]);
            map.put(arr[i], freq+1);
        }
    }

    Set<Integer> freqset = map.keySet();
    for (int val:freqset) 
    {
        int freq = map.get(val);
        if (freq%2 != 0) {
            sum = sum+freq*val;
        }
    }       
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum;     
}
```

}
}}

above solution is not right(as say HackerEarth). Please suggest me an efficient solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You got any solution for that as my solution is too getting failed in the hidden test cases.

package RD;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddSum {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr=new int[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }

    int query=sc.nextInt();
    while(query>0)
    {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hs=new HashMap<>();
        int left=sc.nextInt();
        int right=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=left-1;i<right;i++)
        {
            if(!hs.containsKey(arr[i]))
            {
            hs.put(arr[i],1);
            }
            else
            {
                hs.put(arr[i],hs.get(arr[i])+1);
            }
        }
        int sum=0;
        for(Integer value:hs.keySet())
        {
            if(hs.get(value)%2!=0)
            {
                sum=sum+hs.get(value)*value;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        query--;
    }
}
```

}